# How can I change which background image appears depending on the device the site is being viewed on?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, media-queries

I am trying to have a different image appear depending on the device that the page is being viewed on (either a mobil or a desktop). The issue I am facing is that the images from what I can tell from the design are not background images.

This is what I have done thus far:

```
<main>
  <div class="faq" id="faq">
      <div class="images">
        <img src="./images/illustration-woman-online-mobile.svg" class="woman mobile" alt="">
        <img src="./images/bg-pattern-mobile.svg" class="pattern mobile" alt="">
        <img src="./images/illustration-woman-online-desktop.svg" class="desktop" alt="">
        <img src="./images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg" class="desktop" alt="" srcset="">
        <img src="./images/illustration-box-desktop.svg" class="desktop" alt="" srcset="">
      </div>
      <h1>FAQ</h1>
      <div class="concern team" id="team">
        <div class="section">
          <p class="question">How many team members can I invite?</p>
          <img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="">
        </div>
        <p class="answer">
          You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on
          team members for the Premium plan.
```

and the sass for the html:

```
.faq {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 1rem;
    padding: 2rem 1rem 3rem;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    
    .woman {
        position: absolute;
        top: -119px;
        left: 32px;
        right: 28px;
    }

    .desktop {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .pattern {
        position: relative;
        top: -25px;
        left: 31px;
        // right: ;
    }
```

The issue is when I use visibility hidden on the mobile version for example there's whitespace.

Here's a link to the repo for the complet code [Github](https://github.com/mroungou/faq-accordion-card)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with whitespace when using `visibility: hidden` on the mobile version can be resolved by using `display: none` instead. This will completely hide the element and remove it from the layout, preventing any whitespace from appearing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).